# Devote/dedicate one's time?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms

Is it correct to say:

> I devote/dedicate all my time to task A

or can you only devote/dedicate yourself to something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can clearly see, [OED's entry for devote](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/devote) says

> **Devote:** Give all or most of one’s time or resources to a person ***or*** activity

Same goes for [dedicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dedicate)

> **Dedicate:** Devote (time or effort) to a particular task ***or*** purpose

For added reference, [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dedicate%2Cdevote&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdedicate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevote%3B%2Cc0) shows a higher usage of ***devote***.

Comment: +1 But comparing 'devote' with 'dedicate' without context (as in your Ngram) is to be avoided, IMO. Something like [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dedicate+time%2C+devote+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdedicate%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevote%20time%3B%2Cc0) could have been a bit more specific.

Comment: @MaulikV Noted!

Comment: [Here's another Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dedicated+his+time%2Cdevoted+his+time%2C+devoted+her+time%2C+dedicated+her+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdedicated%20his%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevoted%20his%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevoted%20her%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdedicated%20her%20time%3B%2Cc0)